# What is the partition size needed for The Mavericks install disk?

Tags: install, bootable-disk, macos

I will setup a USB key to install Mavericks.

I would like to know the needed size of the partition to install Mavericks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the Mavericks partition uses 5.36 GB (5,355,311,104 Bytes) (per Disk Utility).  That's 4.98 GB in old-school "binary" types like me (4.98 GiB).

This is subject to change given partition overhead, block size, a Mavericks version.  So I'd allocate a little more to the partition.

Comment: This is very close to my own results.

Comment: the recommended is 8GB

Answer (score 1):

The Mavericks install app is about 5.3GB and it is compressed. That should be how much space it will take up on a USB stick. Just drop the installer on the stick and double click on the installer to install.

Answer (score 1):

I have partitioned my 64 GB USB stick into two parts, one being *5 361 369 088 b* large out of which *5 951 488 b* is free after making it Mavericks installation disk.