# Install Mavericks from usb drive on new HDD

Tags: hard-drive, macos, usb, startup

I replaced my old HDD with a new one. Also I created a bootable usb flash (8GB Toshiba) with Mavericks using DiskMaker X. I restared Mac and pressed Option key, but I see no option to boot from. I understand that I can't see my HDD at the moment because it has not been formatted yet, but I do not see also bootable usb drive. I thought maybe it was created with issues/errors, but when I tried on another Mac, it works, I can boot from usb drive. So I do not understand, what's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried this method : http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106112/11600 ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the bootable USB as the Mavericks USB should be created - it isn't the same way as with Lion/Mountain Lion.

Here is how a bootable USB with Mavericks need to be created: http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/12/make-boot-os-x-mavericks-usb-install-drive/

Comment: I tried but after I mount “InstallESD.dmg”, there is no BaseSystem.dmg there.

Comment: The BaseSystem.dmg in a hidden file inside InstallESD.dmg, so you need to enable the hidden files - eg. like this: http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/

Comment: I followed all the steps, but I can not see usb drive in boot menu after I press Option key. So it's the same result.

Comment: Try a different USB drive. I have certain ones that I haven't ever been able to boot from.

Comment: @Bert, yep I did this way