# Creating a Bootable USB Drive: unable to download Mavericks again

Tags: macos, usb, install

I am following this guide to creating a Bootable USB Drive with Mavericks: [How to Perform a Clean Install of OS X Mavericks](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/10/22/perform-clean-install-os-x-mavericks/)

However, I cannot find the `Install OS X Mavericks.app` file in my Applications folder.

And when I go to the app store I am not able to download Mavericks again. Clicking on "Free" does nothing. I see no option to download anywhere.

[image: no download]

Is there anywhere else that I can get a copy of this file so that I can create the bootable drive?

Comment: Log out and back in the AppStore, you should be able to download the installation file via the AppStore.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can not download Maverics Installer if you already have mavericks.

Next time when you download a major new OS, DO NOT RUN after download.

First find the download and make copy the Installer file.

The reason is the Installer will delete it self after installation is complete.

How to make a Bootable USB for Mavericks has been discussed and answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106088/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-mavericks-install-usb-flash-drive).

Last not least: There is a Recovery (hidden) partition on you drive.

When called upon that one will recover (repair) your mavericks from the Internet. The [recovery can be also done from a USB.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4848) as explained here, it only needs a small USB with 1 gig size.