# Can I download the Yosemite install "app" on a MacBook Air, move it to an install USB drive, and install it on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

That is, is there a difference between the Yosemite install "app" that I would get on the Mac App Store, between the one I would get on a MacBook Air vs. on a MacBook Pro?

Trying to download it on my Air and install it clean on my Pro.

Comment: does the MBP qualifies for 10.10 ?

Comment: You can use the install app on any compatible mac. But the app requires an existing installation of a compatible and functioning OS X to install the new version. If you need you can create Bootable USB drives to install or to fix disk problems following [this procedure](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106112/11600)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Install App that you download from the Mac App Store is a universal installer that isn't tied to a specific model/build.  Similar to the retail installation discs from earlier operating system releases.  It will install properly on any supported systems that meet the [requirements](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475).

So yes, as long as the installer is from the Mac App Store then you should be able to copy it to a thumb drive and install it on any supported Macs.

Comment: That is all correct. Here's some info on how to get Yosemite into a drive just in case http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/18/clean-install-os-x-yosemite/